# ServiceStack StatusResult not filled

Tags: servicestack

I created a simple service with service stack.

```
namespace BE.Source.Listener.Services
{
    public class StatusService : Service
    {
        private ILog Logger
        {
            get
            {
                return LogManager.GetLogger(GetType()); ;
            }

        }
        public object Get(KilnListenerStatusRequest request)
        {

            var result = new KilnListenerStatusResponse();
            result.LastPushRequest = DateTime.Now;

            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

The service returns a dto named "StatusResult" which has the ResponseSTatus property.

The Request and the result dtos are in the same name space but not in the one the serivce is,

Or is StatusREsult only filled when a error occurs ?

```
namespace BE.Source.ServiceModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Request for Service Status
    /// </summary> 
    public sealed class StatusRequest : IReturn<StatusResult>
    {

    }
}



namespace BE.Source.ServiceModel
{

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public sealed class StatusResult
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Status of the response
    /// </summary>
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; } //Automatic exception handling
}
```

But when firing the get with the jsonservice cleint the property is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge the ResponseStatus property will be null when no error has occured.

From [one of the many tests in the ServiceStack GitHub repo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/417bc357baf3b7fae855c605841cb7896b559c7f/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/CustomerServiceValidationTests.cs):

```
[Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(CustomerServiceValidationTests), "ServiceClients")]
public void Post_ValidRequest_succeeds(Func<IServiceClient> factory)
{
    var client = factory();
    var response = client.Send<CustomersResponse>(validRequest);
    Assert.That(response.ResponseStatus, Is.Null);
}
```